# Troubles with creating initial PostgreSQL base

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a new base `/usr/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/data --locale=en_US`and got the following:

```
creating template1 database in /var/lib/pgsql/data/base/1 ... FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Invalid argument
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=35233792, 03600).
... To reduce the request size (currently 35233792 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared_buffers parameter (currently 3584) and/or its max_connections parameter (currently 104).
If the request size is already small, it's possible that it is less than your kernel's SHMMIN parameter, in which case raising the request size or reconfiguring SHMMIN is called for
```

How to fix this? Where can I change these `SHMMAX` and `SHMIN`? Do I really need to recompile the linux kernel as PostgreSQL advises me?

Comment: What Linux distribution?

Comment: all is done, and rock now. Linux is a Fuduntu (fork of Fedora 14)

Comment: Please **always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `root` user, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following lines:

```
kernel.shmmax=2147483648
kernel.shmall=2097152
```

Then run:

```
sysctl -p
```

.. to reload the kernel settings.

That'll set the maximum shared memory segment size to 2Gb & should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, all done! just found answer on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/kernel-resources.html and it is like yours :)

Comment: @Yurij73 You want http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html ; if you link to the `/current/` version of the docs it'll help stop stale links appearing in Google.